# Quotes not auto-closed within brackets in Spyder's Editor

Tags: python, spyder

When I try to insert quotes within a bracket they will not complete. The quotes will auto complete if they are on their own but if I put quotes within a bracket it will not complete and will look like this

["]

Anyone else having this problem?

Comment: This would best be asked on fora for spyder.

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) The reason you're observing this behavior is because quotes are only automatically closed when there's no text to the right of the cursor.